# Highlighting in text area in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table in HTML which has three columns

i.e **Error - User Input - Correct Format**

When I hover over the table the rows highlight

\CSS

```
table tr:hover                
 { 
    font-weight: bolder; 
    color:black;
 }
```

When I hover and do that I want to text also to be highlighted in my text area

i.e if I hover over the first row I want the text in User Input column to also be bold in the text area so the user can see where the error is

i.e **Error -   User Input -   Correct Format**
    Flight ID    12              [0-9]{3}

So as I hover over that row I want it to search the text area for **12** and bolden every **12** it finds and same for other rowns.

### SUMMARY

what ever is in the **USER INPUT column** **bolden** in **text area** if **found**

http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/ so far what I have is this so when u hover over a row in the header one column aswell as boldening the text in there but to also bolden the text found in the text area

Comment: could you setup a http://jsfiddle.net example with your markup/css?

Comment: can't you add a border to td??

Comment: As said, you can’t apply inline markup into a textarea, you need to use a contenteditable. http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think you can add markup (such as a `STRONG` tag) in a textarea. You are also quite limited to what visual styles you can apply.

If you have a `DIV` instead of a textarea (like a contenteditable), you would do something like:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    var ta = $(this).find('.textarea');
    ta.html(ta.html().replace(/12/g,'<strong>12</strong>'));
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of what I *think* you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/4/

You need to use a `contenteditable` DIV to be able to highlight words using markup inside, `textarea` won’t allow it.

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    var text = [];
    $.each($(this).find('td'), function() {
        text.push($.trim($(this).text()));
    });
    highlight(text);
},function() {
    highlight(null);
});

var area = $('div[contenteditable]');

function highlight(what) {
    area.html(area.html().replace(/<strong\/?>/g,''));
    $.each(what || [], function(i, val) {
        area.html(area.html().replace(new RegExp(val,'gi'),'<strong>'+val+'</strong>'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want but it is not possible in a textarea alone then?

Comment: No, a textarea escapes all HTML, so you can't add markup inside it.